# Init connection without sync using Bluetooth Low Energy in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, sensors, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible to init a connection between my mobile phone and a sensor without synchronization between then?

I scan for devices, found my sensor (appear in list with no sync), but when I try to synchronize with it the sensor dissapear from list devices (recently discovered) without reason so I can't syncronize them.

I'm developing using Bluetooh Low Energy in a Motorola Razr and using Bluetooth LE API provided by Motorola here: http://developer.motorola.com/docs/bluetooth-low-energy-api/

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: just to clarify my question, this issue (last paragraph) is in internal application for managing BT connection in Android OS, not in my app.

I just want to know if it possible to connect devices without paired and using Bluetooth Low Energy (important notice).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to paired first. you can not connect the LE device with out paired. you need to do classic pair method first.
Thanks

Comment: As you said, I can't communicate devices without pairing process. Thanks

Comment: This is untrue.  In BLE connection does not require pairing, though some specific services may be set to.